# Infinite recursion for iterator of tied hash with perldbmfilter for filter_fetch_key

Tags: perl, recursion, hash, dbm

I have a Perl tied hash which uses the [`SDBM_File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/SDBM_File) module and I need to do some character encoding conversions when storing or fetching values.

I followed the [documentation of `perldbmfilter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perldbmfilter.pod) and in general it seems to work: I get the results from the hash properly encoded like expected, and it stores the byte values for my encoding in the file, which I check using a hex editor.

What is not working is any kind of iteration over all elements of the hash, either using `keys`, or `each`, or things like `Data::Dumper`, or even a simple copy operation to another hash.

What I always get is an infinite recursion. It seems like the iterator never gets to its end, and if I use `each` and print the iterated values they are repeated.

I hunted the problem down to the use of `filter_fetch_key` and the charset conversion I'm doing there. If I comment out `filter_fetch_key`, or if I change the filter method to do just `return shift`, then the iteration works again. Either of these solves my problem, but I need to use `filter_fetch_key` to send the caller properly-encoded strings.

```
$dbm->filter_fetch_key  (sub { $_ = $self->_normalizeCharset($_); });

sub _normalizeCharset
{
  my $self = shift || Carp::croak(...);

  #return shift;
  return ...::windows2utf(shift);
}
```

If I uncomment `return shift`, the iteration works; but commented like above it doesn't. I guess it has something to do what happens to `$_`, but I have no idea, as `windows2utf` just copies the given data and does some character encoding. This works the same way for storing keys and values and even for fetching values. Only keys are the problem and only if I do an iteration, not if I directly ask for specific keys.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

There's a thread on [`Perlmonks`](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1099905) as well.

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1099905

Comment: It would be nice to see a little more of your code. What is `$dbm`? Do you have a corresponding `filter_store_key`? What is `...::windows2utf`?

Comment: I don't see why you have used a method to do the normalisation. Your filter may as well be `sub { $_ = _normalizeCharset(undef, $_) }` or even `sub { $_ = ...::windows2utf(shift) }` but I can't imagine what the mysterious `...::windows2utf` may be.

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning: Were you betting on which post would get an answer first? Please don't do that. You've heard the last from me.

Comment: Yes, I hoped to double my chances to get useful answers, because not all people use the same community. And regarding your other questions: I appreciate anyones help, but my code is obviously stripped down to what I thought is the most important thing to trigger changes in the problem I see. It simply doesn't matter if I use a method or not, neither does the availability of filter_store_key. I have one, but that shouldn't matter because it doesn't change anything regarding my problem and not having one would be allowed according to the docs as well.

Comment: windows2utf is just a wrapper around a bunch of other functions which do charset encoding and I thought it would be more clear to understand the problem and get some hints if I reduced the amount of code to the minimum required to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue: During the tests I recognized that `filter_fetch_key` calls my function once with a key value of `undef` and my functions return an empty string for convenience in that case. This seems to be what's causing the infinite loop, I guess someone wants to add that empty string as a new key to the hash for some reason and runs into problems with some iterator which gets invalid or such. The interesting part about that is that changes to keys should be perfectly fine, because one of the examples in the documentation is exactly about that and my tests show that I can replace each key except the `undef` one which whatever I like, I can create completely new keys by prepending __ for example. No problem, only if I don't return `undef` for `undef` I get the infinite loop. The first version of the following method works, the second does not.

```
sub _normalizeCharset
{
  my $self  = shift || Carp::croak(...);
  my $value = shift;
  my $key = shift || 0;
return undef unless (defined($value));
#return '' unless (defined($value));

$value = "__$value" if ($key);

  return ...::windows2utf($value);
}


sub _normalizeCharset
{
  my $self  = shift || Carp::croak(...);
  my $value = shift;
  my $key = shift || 0;
#return undef unless (defined($value));
return '' unless (defined($value));

$value = "__$value" if ($key);

  return ...::windows2utf($value);
}
```

I guess `undef` may be some special signal of the filter to indicate the end of iterated keys or such and simply is not meant as a regular hash key. At least I don't put it anywhere.